# How could I concatenate 3 videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I got the following command for concatenating 2 videos, now if I want to concatenate more than 2 videos then how could I do?

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i outro.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts" -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

Kindly help me with this. I saw other questions also but those commands are different.

TIA